# Event driven simulation: When inserting new events into a priority queue, do old events become redundant?

Tags: c, priority-queue, event-simulation

I created a binary heap based priority queue in C. I'm trying to create a discrete event simulation.

Here's what I understand about event simulation:

Suppose I have 10 values in my priority queue, each value representing an event. For each value in the PQ, the program wil dequeue an value and insert 10 more values. In other words, the program is making new calculations for those 10 events.

But what happens to the old values in the PQ? Since new values are being enqueued for every event, shouldn't the previous values become redundant? Shouldn't they be removed from the PQ so that the PQ doesn't get too large?

Comment: If you remove 1 item from a list, and then add 10 items to this list, you will obviously end up with 9 items more than when you started, so it's unclear what process this is supposed to simulate.

Answer (score 0):

Pending events in your priority queue event list remain there until 1) they are polled and become the active event, or 2) they are cancelled (explicitly deleted from the priority queue) due to the logic of a different active event.

For example, consider a simplistic air traffic simulation.  A take-off event will schedule an arrival event at the target destination at some specified time.  However, a weather event or an emergency event might cancel the scheduled arrival, and either reschedule it with an additional delay or divert the airplane to arrive at a different destination with a different time.  However, unless you explicitly cancelled the originally scheduled arrival, that event would be pending on the event list until its scheduled time rolled around.

Bottom line, there's no magic.  It's up to you as the modeler to schedule or cancel events in a way that reflects the correct logic of your model.  The priority queue just does the bookkeeping to handle the execution order.